# asp.net 4.0: datagrid uses control state or view state

Tags: c#, asp.net

can any one tell me that in asp.net 4.0, datagrid uses control state or view state to manage its state in postbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGrid or GridView?  I know the GridView stores essential properties to the Grid's operation in control state, and everything else in viewstate.  So the answer is both.  That way, when the page's viewstate is off, the essentials still work.

HTH.